# AWS Lambda: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-sam

I am developing a REST API in `NodeJs` using `AWS Lambda` and `AWS API Gateway`. I am using `AWS SAM` Template as well.

Below is my NodeJS Code. There I am only trying to access a sample API over the internet and make a `POST` call.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});

exports.testApi = async (event, context) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    con.config.namedPlaceholders = true;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        return response;
    }

    let body = JSON.parse(event.body)

    if (body.key == null ) {
        console.log("fire 1");
        var response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
        return response;
    }


    try {

        let key = body.key;

        console.log("body", body);

        var notificationMessage = {
            "key": key
        };

        

        const notificationResponse = await fetch("https://reqbin.com/sample/post/json", {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(notificationMessage),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const data = await notificationResponse.json();

        //Return the response
        var response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "message": data
            }),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        }; 

        return response;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        //Return the response
        var response = {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "error": error
            }),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        }; 

        return response;
    }


};
```

Below is my `template.yaml` file. It contains nested access to another template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  xxx-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for xxx-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-xxxx
          - subnet-aaaa
          - subnet-bbbb
          - subnet-cccc
          - subnet-dddd
          - subnet-eeee


Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  #Dont create this domain in the AWS Console manually, so it will fail here
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: api2.someapp.com

Resources:

  # Authentication required HTTP API
  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxx:certificate/bac44716-xxxx-431b-xxxx-xxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: xxxxxxx
          IpV6: true
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer

  # Authentication NOT required HTTP API
  NoAuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        BasePath: noauth
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxx-420d-xxx-xxx-xxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: xxxxxx

        
# Lambda settings
  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  SharedValueOutput:
    Value: !Ref FirebaseProjectId        
    Description: You can refer to any resource from the template.
  # HelloWorldApi:
  #   Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
  #   Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

Below is the nested template file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  xxx-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for xxx-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-xxx
          - subnet-aaa
          - subnet-ccc
          - subnet-sss
          - subnet-fff
          - subnet-eee

Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  DomainName:
    Type: String

Resources:

  NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod

  
  MyApiMapping:
    DependsOn: NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
    Properties:
      ApiMappingKey: no-auth
      DomainName: api2.xxx.com
      ApiId: !Ref NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2
      Stage: !Ref NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2.Stage

  
  
  TestPostFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: xxx-restapi/
      Handler: source/fcm/test-api.testApi
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetRtcTokenAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: /fcm/test-api
            Method: post
            ApiId: !Ref NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2
```

When I executed the lambda function in local environment it works fine. But if i executed the same after uploading to AWS, it gives me the following error with `503` status code.

```
{
    "message": "Service Unavailable"
}
```

Below is my Cloud Watch log.

```
START RequestId: e84242ea-xxx-4aa0-xxx-xxx Version: $LATEST
2022-06-12T05:55:52.914Z    e84242ea-xxx-4aa0-xxx-xxx   INFO    body { key: 'value' }
END RequestId: e84242ea-xxx-xxx-dd37f2a005c0
REPORT RequestId: e84242ea-xxx-4aa0xxx993e-xxx  Duration: 30032.56 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 72 MB  Init Duration: 315.65 ms    
2022-06-12T05:56:22.936Z xxx-b568-xxx-993e-xxx Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

The `timed out` error you see above is just a mask to the real problem. I even tried this with time limit set to 2 minutes, same result. In my local environment with Docker this works in seconds.

After googling I figured out I "may" have not enabled internet connection from my Lambda functions to outside. Even in my API, all Lambda functions that require no Lambda to  outside internet connection is working fine.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I got the 503 error as well,
turns out to be the Api Gateway timeout problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to debug the networking aspect. Can anything in those subnets connect to the database? Are the security groups correct?

You might find it easier to create an EC2 instance and debug the networking from there. It certainly seems like a connection timing out.